# Prove T is a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. Given that $T: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ $(Tx,Ty) = (x,y)$, how should we prove that T is an linear operator?

It is not hard to show that
$$(T(x+y), Tz) = (Tx + Ty, Tz),(T(ax), Tz) = (aTx, Tz)$$

But, how may I show that $Tz$ can be any element of $\mathcal{H}$?

It seems that all theorems relies on linear operator...

Answer (score 1):

Use the inner product relation to calculate $\|T(x+y)-(Tx+Ty)\|^2$ and likewise $\|aTx-T(ax)\|^2$. You'll find that they are both zero. I'll do the second one and leave the first for you to check:

\begin{align*}
\|aTx-T(ax)\|^2 & = (aTx-T(ax), aTx-T(ax)) \\
& = (aTx,aTx)-2(aTx,T(ax)+(T(ax),T(ax)) \\
& = a^2(Tx,Tx)-2a(Tx,T(ax))+(T(ax),T(ax))\\
& = a^2(x,x)-2a(x,ax)+(ax,ax) \\
& = a^2\|x\|^2-2a^2\|x\|^2+a^2\|x\|^2 = 0.
\end{align*}

Note that I've implicitly assumed the Hilbert space is real. The calculation works basically the same way in the complex case though.

After you check for yourself that $\|T(x+y)-(Tx+Ty)\|^2=0$, just appeal to the fact that $\|v\|=0$ if and only if $v=0$. Thus $T(x+y) = Tx+Ty$ and $T(ax)=aTx$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!